# Apache 2.4 giving error "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /static/ on this server" while deploying Django on Fedora

Tags: django, apache, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I am new to django and facing this forbidden error while deploying django on apache. I have tried almost all the solutions available on google but still didn't get over this issue.

Currently I am using:

- Python3.6
- Apache 2.4
- Fedora 28

I also tried moving my project into /var/www but that also doesn't work for me.

This is how my httpd.conf file looks:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName rohit.com
DocumentRoot /home/rohit/django_ionic/
ServerAdmin root@localhost


Alias /static /home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx/static
<Directory "/home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx/static">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx/drfx>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess mysite1 python-path=/home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx:/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite1
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx/drfx/wsgi.py
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

<Directory /home/rohit/django_ionic/drfx/drfx/>
<Files wsgi.py>
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also given the chown permissions to my django file folder.
One more issue is my user and group is apache and I have seen a alot of solutions using user and group as www-data:www-data. Is that realy making any difference as I have given permissions by using apache:apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mixed configurations from version 2.x and 2.4.

[From the docs:](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

> So even if mixing configuration is still possible, please try to avoid
>   it when upgrading: either keep old directives and then migrate to the
>   new ones on a later stage or just migrate everything in bulk.

From the docs:

*In this example, there is no authentication and all requests are denied.*

**2.2 configuration:**

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

**2.4 configuration:**

```
Require all denied
```

*In this example, there is no authentication and all requests are allowed.*

**2.2 configuration:**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

**2.4 configuration:**

```
Require all granted
```